# Rename columns in a dataframe the same name as list elements in R

Tags: r

I have a large list of file names ["fname1","fname2",..."fname50"].

I would like to change the column names the dataframe I'm working with to match the file names. For example, column1's name should change to fname1, column2's name to fname2, and so on. Actual column names are results of cbind and are pretty long/messy so it's not just one-word replacements or anything.

I can do this as a one-off

```
>names(df)[1]<-filenames[1]
```

However, I am having trouble making this work in a loop.

```
>for(i in df){names(df)[i]<-filenames[i]}
>error msg: 'names' attribute [39] must be the same length as the vector [5]
```

I usually work in Python and am probably treating loops incorrectly in R. I would appreciate tips and tricks. Thank you!

In pseudo-Python, what I'm looking for is:

```
    for i in df-colnames:
        df-colnames[i] = filenames[i]
```

Comment: Simply `names(df) <- filenames`

Comment: Even in Python pandas, you can avoid loops as columns are lists: `df.columns = filenames`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless if it's a list or a vector, you can simply do

```
names(df) = filenames
```

Comment: @HubertL Sorry about that, I posted 2-3 minutes after you but that's because I was looking into something else at the same time. There was no comment when I started typing.

Comment: As HubertL commented above, this is the easiest way to do it. Thank you everyone, this solved my problem. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df){
names(df[,i]) = filenames[i]}
```

Comment: As shown in other answer, looping can be avoided here

Comment: That's true. For some reason, I was assuming that the number of columns might not always be equal to number of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The solution:

```
names(df)<-filesnames
```

Thank you everyone that commented. This worked.

Comment: @suren: it is commendable that you would like to edit some answers, and I very much welcome useful edits to any of my material. However, you have added a grammatical error into this one, and furthermore it is not an edit we would regard as substantive - we want improvements, not edits for the sake of them. The numbers of badly written and badly formatted posts out there is astronomical, so it may be worth fixing those first!

Comment: @suren: [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40573198) you have added two errors: another grammatical error, and punctuation marks need to be followed by a space.

Comment: please don't feel bad. i am here to improve your skills of writing. so it will help you.

Comment: @suren: in that case, I will be asking a moderator to look at your edits. Edits motivated by spite or retaliation are not welcome here.

Comment: please correct those i will again review and try to correct.

Comment: you can ask moderator but as my things is not for you.its for community dear.

Comment: @suren - Retaliating against halfer by editing their posts to insert grammatically incorrect wording is childish and needs to stop immediately.

Comment: @Bradlarson please check the all things replied by halfer.some of them are not even understable,some of them are not even related to context.i am sure 90 percent replies contains the grammatical error.if someone don't know the rules of grammer then how he can comment about grammer.just take en example: if you are a judge of dance reality show but you dont know any single thing about dance then how you can justify weather they are doing wrong or right.